# How can i Archive this Type of slider in Flutter Mobile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

In one of my projects, I have to design a slider like the below image for appointments. Here users can choose the start and end time. also if the slot is not available then the user can not select that time slot.
How can I achieve this functionality in flutter?

[image]

Comment: ask your same question here https://discord.gg/TN5xuQ4x

Comment: Hi, maybe one of these packages are good enough for you: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_select_items or https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter